# Does WPF & Windows Form have some control behavior similar to div

Tags: wpf, winforms, html, controls

In HTML, we have element div,  I wonder if there is equivalent control in WPF or window Forms? 
thanks

Edit

I am looking for a control which behaves similar to the following HTML code.  Say I have a button "Add Columns", when the button is clicked,  a window shows up under the button, the window has checkboxes, buttons, labels and when users click a button in the window, it will run code in click event handler.

One more thing, the window is not modal and should stay open. when the window is Open, users can click other part of parent UI.

```
<button class="btn" id='add_columns'>Add Columns</button>
<div id="addcolumns_dropdown"  class="columns_dropdown">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div id='columns'> 
    <table id='cols'></table>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons_div" style="display:none" id="select_cols_done_div">    
    <button class="btns" id='done_cols'>Done</button>
    <button class="btns" id='cancel_cols'>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What specific behavior are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a control which behaves similar to the above HTML code.  Say I have a button "Add Columns", when the button is clicked,  a window shows up under the button, the window is like a regular window, it has checkbox, buttons, labels.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It makes it much clearer what you're asking. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` is just a layout container, WPF has many Layout containers `Grid`, `StackPanel` etc. each one has certain layouts so you can just choose the one that best suits your needs.